# Windows Phone - difference between ProtectedData & DataProtectionProvider classes?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, cryptography

I see 2 different classes used to encrypt and store application data.

There is

```
  ProtectedData.Protect Method (Byte[], Byte[], DataProtectionScope)
```

and there is

```
DataProtectionProvider.ProtectAsync
```

The `DataProtectionProvider` does not take a entropy parameter unlike the other one. The documentation isn't clear on why not - if I don't use entropy, then other apps on the phone would also be able to decrypt it, right (if they were able to get hold of it).

What is the difference between `DataProtectionProvider` & `ProtectedData` classes? Which is supposed to be used where?

I am targetting my App for 8.1 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple difference is that `ProtectedData.Protect` is available in Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 Silverlight and `DataProtectionProvider.ProtectAsync` is available Windows Phone 8.1 XAML.